# Java Program doesn't work after exported from eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

When I open the runnable jar file, it still could be opened but it get stuck after half a second like this.
(I cannot post an image, so I post the image here: https://pbs.twimg.com/media/B4RN2_MCYAAi1DD.png)

It works well in eclipse.
When I run it in CMD, it says:

```
Exception in thread "game" java.lang.NullPointerException: in
        at javazoom.jl.decoder.Bitstream.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at javazoom.jl.player.Player.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at javazoom.jl.player.Player.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at lian.xiangru.game.AudioHandler.<init>(AudioHandler.java:12)
        at lian.xiangru.game.GameBoard.playSound(GameBoard.java:410)
        at lian.xiangru.game.GameBoard.move(GameBoard.java:224)
        at lian.xiangru.game.GameBoard.moveTiles(GameBoard.java:271)
        at lian.xiangru.game.GameBoard.checkKeys(GameBoard.java:340)
        at lian.xiangru.game.GameBoard.update(GameBoard.java:146)
        at lian.xiangru.game.Game.update(Game.java:42)
        at lian.xiangru.game.Game.run(Game.java:77)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

It seems something goes wrong with my resources.

This is my playSound method:

```
    private void playSound() {
    // how to play mp3 https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f-7cgX_I220
    AudioHandler sound = new AudioHandler(
            SOUND_LIST[(int) Math.round((Math.log(highestValue) / Math.log(2))) - 1]);
    sound.start();

}
```

This is my AudioHandler class:

```
import javazoom.jl.decoder.JavaLayerException;
import javazoom.jl.player.Player;

class AudioHandler extends Thread {

    private Player playMP3;

    public AudioHandler(String mp3) {
        try {
            playMP3 = new Player(getClass().getResourceAsStream(mp3));
        } catch (JavaLayerException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    public void run() {

        try {
            playMP3.play();
        } catch (JavaLayerException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

The lists are:

```
public static final String[] SOUND_LIST = { "/mayuri.mp3", "/mikoto.mp3",
        "/gai.mp3", "/shougo.mp3", "/gintoki.mp3", "/inori.mp3",
        "/yuzuru.mp3", "/misaki.mp3", "/armin.mp3", "/alphonse.mp3",
        "/alphonse.mp3", "/akane.mp3", "/armin.jpg" };

public static final String[] QUOTE_LIST = { "/mayuri.txt", "/mikoto.txt",
        "/gai.txt", "/shougo.txt", "/gintoki.txt", "/inori.txt",
        "/yuzuru.txt", "/misaki.txt", "/armin.txt", "/alphonse.txt",
        "/alphonse.txt", "/akane.txt", "/armin.txt" };

public static final String[] ICON_LIST = {"/mayuri.jpg", "/mikoto.jpg",
    "/gai.jpg", "/shougo.jpg", "/gintoki.jpg", "/inori.jpg",
    "/yuzuru.jpg", "/misaki.jpg", "/armin.jpg", "/alphonse.jpg",
    "/alphonse.jpg", "/akane.jpg", "/armin.jpg" 
};
```

Thank you !!

Comment: Obviously the random index of `SOUND_LIST[]` returns a Null Reference. Handle that and your problem is solved.

Comment: Can we see SOUND_LIST please?

Comment: And what's the value of highestValue?

Comment: @almasshaikh highestValue is the highestValue of the tiles on the board(2048 game).

Comment: My first guess is that it's not finding your files. Put a debug line in to see is this is the case. Use new File(SOUND_LIST[0]).exists() or similar.

Comment: @RobertBain it says false....

Comment: Well there's your problem. The relative path to your files is incorrect. Are you running your jar in the same folder as your files?

Comment: @RobertBain I can see my resource files in the same jar. here is the picture: https://pbs.twimg.com/media/B4RQ-X_CMAA42Ek.png

Comment: @RobertBain but then it get stuck

Comment: Try removing the forward slashes from the start of your file names.

Comment: @RobertBain then it even doesn't work at all. no window appears.

Comment: @RobertBain I just found the reason. see my answer below and thank you very very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found the reason!

There is a file called Mikoto.mp3 in my resources folder and I typed it as mikoto.mp3 in my code. This could be allowed when I use eclipse to run it. But when I run the runnable jar file, it fails because it is case sensitive.

When I change the file name to mikoto.mp3, it works!

Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 1):

NullPointerException when loading a resource usually means that the resource could not be found. This behavior is different than the normal file open, no exception is thrown.

Are your audio files included in your jar? If not, make sure that when you export the Jar, you set the right options so they are included. A better alternative might be to introduce a real build process into your application if you need repeatability.

Comment: yeah they are included, I can see them we I open the jar with my 7zip.

Comment: Are they in the root of the jar file?

Comment: I just found the reason and thanks for your answer!!

Comment: I notice that the case of some of the resources is different than the names in your lists. Could it be that Eclipse's classloader is papering over this difference and when you run the jar straight up the default classloader behaves differently?

Comment: Yeah you are right! I just wrote an answer. The reason is really funny. It seems that eclipse is not case sensitive when it comes to a file's name.

Comment: I prefer Netbeans, although it's not what it used to be after Oracle took it over. Is still free. Lots of people *love* IntelliJ.